# Slow rotating carousal slider react-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

OK, so I built a carousel slider with React-bootstrap but I am having trouble figuring out how to make the content continuously slide while being able to control the speed. Sort of like a logo slider. It currently behaves as normal with a set interval, then pauses, then flips to next slide. But I want it continuous.

Is there an animation rule or an api I'm missing that is provided by react-bootstrap. Thanks!

```
<Carousel slide={true} wrap={true} touch={true} indicators={false} interval={0} variant='light'>
    <Carousel.Item >
      <AvatarsTemplate name={name} alt={alt} src={src} des={des} />
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <AvatarsTemplate name={name1} alt={alt1} src={src1} des={des1} />
    </Carousel.Item>
    <Carousel.Item>
      <AvatarsTemplate name={name2} alt={alt2} src={src2} des={des2} />
    </Carousel.Item>
  </Carousel>
  <Box sx={{ mt: 5 }}><button>LET'S ORDER</button></Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such animation in react-bootstrap Carousel API. What you could try though, is setting slide to false (so you have no animation on change) and interval to x seconds. Then use css animations, where you also define a scroll of x seconds. In the end it should look like a contionous slider.

Or you use another library with such built-in functionality (I did it with splidejs) and style it with bootstrap classes.

Comment: What css animation do you reccomend? translate3d?

Comment: I'm not into css animations, so I can't really recommend you anything. Translate3d sounds good though. Please mark the question as solved if it answers your initial question.